# Adding center constraints to UILabel in Xamarin UITableViewCell does not center label

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When I put a single label in a custom UITableViewCell for testing and center the label using constraints it ends up not being centered at all.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'd prefer to do this all in code but must use the visual designer. What am I missing?

Further depiction of what seems to be ContentView being wider than the screen width:

[image]

Comment: Have you set the TextAlignment of the label ? label.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;

Comment: I did not change the default alignment

Comment: so did you solve the issue?

Comment: Given the layout constraints placed on the UILabel there is no text alignment that should end in the label text being where it is in that image. I've added another image to further demonstrate that the contentview seems to be much larger than the cell

Comment: Check your table view constraints and label constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up lying outside of the `UITableView` and the `UITableViewCell`. The view controller that the table is embedded in had `auto layout` and `use size classes` enabled. Disabling those for the host view controller fixed the problem.

I discovered the issue once I put a breakpoint on the line of code that set the `UITableView` bounds. It showed that the parent bounds it was inheriting from had a width of 600.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your pictures, then I see that UITableViewCell is constrained correctly and it should be in the middle. Even without the helping borders, which shows that content is wider, I saw that the main window or some other subview has some missing constraints.

I don't know if you're using Table view or somehow populating cells into scroll view, but you should probably check constraints on all 4 sides for scrollview/table view, to be sure that it takes all the space. If you're sure that the constraints are there, then you can try to set the same width as scrollview or content( if you're using tableview ).

[image: Set width to subview]

After this it should create same screen width constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I think You should add `leading` and `trailing` constraints to your label. that should stop them from spreading out of the boundaries. also I would suggest adding `top` and `bottom` constraints to handle auto resizing based on your label's text content.

If you add all these four constraints then horizontal and vertical `centre` constraints will not be required.